# How do I combine 2 queries from difference tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 queries. The 1st is to find the netamount and the 2nd is the sum of budget. i need to show the result including the store name and storenumber which are from difference table.

Here is my 1st Query to find total netamount:

```
SELECT sum(a.netamt) as netamt, b.store_name 
  FROM site_sales a JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum = a.storenum 

  WHERE a.busidate >= '2017-01-01' AND a.busidate <='2017-04-30'
  GROUP BY a.storenum
```

The 2nd Query  is to find total budget

```
SELECT

SUM(CASE WHEN c.busidate BETWEEN '2017-01' AND '2017-04' THEN c.budget ELSE 0 END) as budget,
b.store_name
FROM site_kpimthslsbgt c JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum = c.storenum 
GROUP BY c.storenum
```

I need to combine both of this query. The result of output should be 
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxRls.png)

Comment: Post output of the individual queries as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this Also you need to put up join conditions in the end if there are multiple records fetched in your individual queries :

```
Select x.netamt, y.budget, y.store_name
from
(
SELECT sum(a.netamt) as netamt, b.store_name 
FROM site_sales a JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum = a.storenum 
WHERE a.busidate >= '2017-01-01' AND a.busidate <='2017-04-30'
GROUP BY a.storenum
) x
inner join
(
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN c.busidate BETWEEN '2017-01' AND '2017-04' THEN c.budget ELSE 0 END) as budget,
b.store_name
FROM site_kpimthslsbgt c JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum = c.storenum 
GROUP BY c.storenum
) y
on x.store_name = y.store_name
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. This query give a perfect calculation for both table. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(a.netamt) as netamt,SUM(CASE WHEN c.busidate BETWEEN '2017-01' AND '2017-04' THEN c.budget ELSE 0 END) as budget,b.store_name
FROM site_store b
JOIN site_kpimthslsbgt c ON b.storenum = c.storenum 
JOIN site_sales a ON  b.storenum = a.storenum 
GROUP BY b.storenum
```

Try above query.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have try this query, it give result, but wrong calculation for both netamount and budget.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 4 possible scenarios here, stores which have sales and budget, stores which have sales but no budget, stores which have budget but no sales, stores which have neither sales nor budget.

Given

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS site_sales,site_budget;
CREATE TABLE site_sales(ID INT auto_increment primary key, site_id int, busidate date,amt int);

create table site_budget(ID INT auto_increment primary key, site_id int, busidate date,amt int);

insert into site_sales (site_id,busidate,amt) values
(1,'2017-04-01',10),(1,'2017-04-01',20),
(2,'2017-04-01',10);

insert into site_budget (site_id,busidate,amt) values
(1,'2017-04-01',200),
(3,'2017-04-01',100);
```

This query

```
SELECT b.name, 
        sum(case when  a.busidate between '2017-01-01' and '2017-04-30' then a.amt else 0 end) as netamt,
        ifnull((select SUM(CASE WHEN c.busidate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-04-30' THEN c.amt ELSE 0 END) from site_budget c where b.id = c.site_id ),0) as budget
FROM sites b
left JOIN site_sales a ON  b.id = a.site_id 
GROUP BY b.id
```

result

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| name   | netamt | budget |
+--------+--------+--------+
| Store1 |     30 |    200 |
| Store2 |     10 |      0 |
| Store3 |      0 |    100 |
| Store4 |      0 |      0 |
+--------+--------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thankyou so much ! your query also work perfectly. It give correct calculation for both netamount and budget follow it store name. :)